# Writing many MySQL (in vsCode) queries in one file. How to avoid writting 'USE DBaseName" constantly?

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-code, wampserver

I'm learning SQL / MySQL using WAMPSERVER and the MySql extension for vsCode, so that I can write, comment and keep the code in the vsCode editor, instead of sending volatile queries with the command line. 
This morning I created a database by right-clicking a database / New Query:
[image]

After creating it this way, I was able to create code that I run without having to write `USE DBaseName` before the selected lines, as in the selected three lines you can see below:
[image]

Yet, after restarting my laptop at home, the same code will not run. It returns the usual

```
undefined
Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected
```

unless I write the `USE` statement, as in the last group (4 lines) of code. So I have to write that every time I want to try a query...

Why did it work this morning and not now? How can one run queries without having to constantly write `USE DBaseName`?

(links to explanations to further understand the underlying mechanism are also very welcome...)

EDIT: posting image of server in vsCode to answer comment: 
I'm using a local server (pic below) which hasn't changed since this morning...

[image]

Comment: Use fully qualified table names.

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1, but how does that explain that it did work this morning with the same unqualified table names?

Comment: I haven't used vsCode but I assume you have to set up the connection, correct? If that is the case, did the connection have a default database specified when it was working, that it no longer has now that it is not?

Comment: The server hasn't changed and I haven't changed the default DB (updated question with pic of server and database selected), but I will further investigate which one is the default db now. Will update as soon as I find sth...

Comment: There isn't any default database...

Comment: Also, using fully qualified names in many cases might imply writing even more than using the line USE DBaseName...

Comment: Got it. Select code, right-click it and selecting Run MySQL Query returns an error (nothing else done in vsCode). But when I created the file I'm using now, I did it, not by selecting a folder / New File, but by right-clicking on a DB / New Query. Doing that, lines of code run using that database w/out USE statement. Until I restart vsCode  - it won't open that or any DB by default, although Uueerdo might also meant this by "default". Then, if I saved that file, after restarting, there won't be any DB selected, but right clicking a DB and selecting New Query allows to Run MySQL Query w/out USE